# Access a method from another form

Tags: c#, forms, methods

In my main form I have this method to stop a timer:

```
public  void resettimer()
{
    ShutdownTimer.Stop();
}
```

Now I need to activate this methode when a buttom was clicked on another form. This is how i coded it:

```
private void btn_doorgaan_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    //bib_main is how the first form is called

    Bib_main MainMenu = new Bib_main();
    MainMenu.resettimer();
}
```

This is also what I find on the internet but nothing happens, the methode never triggers.

Can u guys tell me what i am doing wrong or if their is a better way to stop the timer in the other form when the buttom is clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create the new form, you should include a reference to your existing form (the one with the method). Than with that reference you can call the method, instead of creating a new instance of Bib_main.

EDIT:

Constructor of the form should look like this:

```
private Bib_Main _mainForm;

public SomeForm(Bib_Main mainForm)
{
    // store the reference to a field
    _mainForm = mainForm;
}
```

When creating the new form in the main form:

```
SomeForm newForm = new SomeForm(this);
```

Then you can just call it like:

```
_mainForm.resettimer();
```

Comment: Could you give an example caus I don't know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't just make a new `Bib_main` object and call the method on it. You need to call the method on your existing `Bib_main`.

Comment: Could you give an example caus I don't know how to do this?